# how to Configure VLC using fPIC?

Tags: vlc, configure, fpic

It's the first time i apply for GSoc ,and i have error in building , and it says to recompile with -fPIC.

[image]

I have tried to re-compile using `./configure --extra-cflags="-fPIC"`

It says:

> unrecognized option: `--extra-cflags=-fPIC'

how to configure using fPIC ?